# Populate ReactNative ListView with Firebase data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've been struggling for a few days to get this working. I want to populate a ListView in React Native with data from my Firebase database. I have this setup:

```
const ListItem = require('./profileRow');

var database = firebase.database();
var userId, dataKey;



    class Selection extends Component {


      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        this.dataRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId + '/profiles_info');

          this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
              rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            })
          };

      }

      listenForProfiles(dataRef){
        dataRef.on('value', (snap) => {

          var profiles = [];
          snap.forEach((child) => {
            profiles.push({
              name: child.val().forename,
              _key: child.key
            });
          });
          alert(profiles);
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(profiles)
          });
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.listenForProfiles(this.dataRef);
      }

      render() {


          return (
            <Image source={require('../assets/bg.png')} style={styles.container}>

            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
            <Text>
              Select a profile to view:
            </Text>

            </View>

            <View style={{flex: 1}}>

            <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)} enableEmptySections={true} style={styles.listview}> </ListView>

            </View>

            </Image>
          );

      }

      _renderItem(item) {
        return (
          <ListItem item={item}/>
        );
      }

    }
```

The datastructure looks like this:
[image]

So what I'm trying to do here is populate each row of the ListView with the "forename" String of each "profile" directory (0,1,2).
But on my alert() I am returned: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` which must mean it is only fetching the directories as Objects from "profiles_info" and not each "forename" String from those directories.

This is where I am stuck, I hope someone can shed some light on this. I know what the solution should be, I just don't know how to apply it in code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing objects into your profiles array here, so it makes sense that your alerts are showing objects:

```
profiles.push({
    name: child.val().forename,
    _key: child.key
});
```

If you use `alert(JSON.stringify(profiles));` instead of `alert(profiles);` you should see an array of objects with fields `name` and `key`.  Accessing `profiles[0].name` would give the actual name.

Side note, if you use [`console.log`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write) instead of `alert` you get some more meaningful information.

Comment: Thank you Jeff , finally got it going.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Tutorial. may be help you.

[react-native-firebase-tutorial-list](http://bitvbit.blogspot.in/2016/08/react-native-firebase-tutorial-list.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked at it before and I'm essentially using the same method as that tutorial demonstrates. My question is more about how I can iterate through the correct directory and fetch the specific data from each directory into my Listview.